# How do you disable linting when using vue-cli serve?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli

I am running my project with vue-cli using the command:

> vue-cli-service serve --open

How do I disable all linting, currently it's re-linting every time I save and it takes way too long to make code changes.

I've put:

```
lintOnSave: false,
```

in my vue.config.js but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a file called `vue.config.js` in your root directory with the code:

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false
}
```

Should probably do the trick.

Comment: Actually I did that (noted above in my original post) and no luck, could it be the fact that I am using typescript?

Comment: Right, I guess I'm tired or something..
I run typescript for my vue projects as well and generated the projects using vue-cli.
Currently running [3.0.0-beta.6](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.md#300-beta6-2018-03-06) on a few projects where the `lintOnSave: false` flag works.

Skimmed through the changes and different issues tracked in the official repository. I noted that there seams to be various issues for different beta releases which affects incompatibility with various `vue.config.js` parameters.

Comment: I solved this by adding "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.vue", "tests/**/*.ts"] to my tsconfig.json file.